# Apache Camel: Polling consumer

Tags: apache-camel, polling, producer-consumer

I'm new to Apache Camel and I'm trying to understand and use the Polling Consumer EIP in a simple project but I feel a little bit lost..
Could someone please help me with a little explanation or even with a little working example.

Any help would be appreciated
Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Have you already read the [manual](http://camel.apache.org/polling-consumer)? What are your problems? What have you tried?

Comment: You can take a look to the `File Component` to see how it works: https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=camel.git;a=tree;f=camel-core/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/component/file;h=1bafb40aa586b1f7af15a79b5657ee6f210aea18;hb=HEAD

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for most use cases, you can create a consumer by just defining them in the `from()` clause in a route...

```
from("activemq:inbox").to(new MyProcessor());
```

but, you can also write your own POJO polling consumer logic for more control over the consumer logic...simply initiate it periodically with a timer and call the `receive()` method as follows:

```
from("timer://foo?period=5000").bean(MyBean, "processQueue");

public void processQueue() {
    while (true) {
        // receive the message from the queue, wait at most 3 sec
        String msg = consumer.receiveBody("activemq:inbox", 3000, String.class);
        if (msg == null) {
            // no more messages in queue
            break;
        }

        // do something with body
    }
}
```

see the docs for more details: http://camel.apache.org/polling-consumer

Comment: Thanks a lot :) i understand now. The problem is that I'm really new to spring and Camel and just can't find enough resources. I'm trying with the Camel In Action book but I find it a bit complicated at times. Anyway thank you for your answer it was really helpful for me :)

Answer (score 1):

Camel supports implementing the Polling Consumer from the EIP patterns using the PollingConsumer interface which can be created via the Endpoint.createPollingConsumer() method.

This is also known as a synchronous receiver, because the receiver thread blocks until a message is received. We call it a Polling Consumer because the receiver polls for a message, processes it, then polls for another. As a convenience, messaging API’s usually provide a **receive()** method that blocks until a message is delivered, in addition to methods like **receiveNoWait()** and **receive(0)** that return immediately if no message is available.

Eg

**ActiveMq Consumer**

```
<from uri="activemq:someQueue"/>
<to uri="direct:somepath"/>
```

**Periodic Consumer**

```
<from uri="timer://foo?period=5000"/>
 <to uri="direct:somepath"/>
```

For more information regarding [Polling Consumer](http://camel.apache.org/polling-consumer.html)